# Check method existence on a template with SFINAE on VS2015

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I would like to know if a templated type has a 'push_back' method.
I tried this example : [Is it possible to write a template to check for a function's existence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence/264088#264088)

my code :

```
template <typename T>
class has_push_back
{
    typedef char one;
    typedef long two;

    template <typename C> static one test(char[sizeof(&C::push_back)]);
    template <typename C> static two test(...);

public:
    enum { value = (sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(char)) };
};
```

My call :

```
    template <typename T>
    HTTPMessage Serializer::GetHTTPMessage(T varToSerialize)
    {
       std::cout << has_push_back<T>::value << std::endl;
       //some code
    }
```

Unfortunatly I got this error when GetHTTPMessage is called with std::string :

> 'overloaded-function': illegal sizeof operand
>
> note: see reference to class template instantiation 'has_push_back'
>   being compiled
>            with
>            [
>               T=std::string
>            ]

I don't understand why it does not compile.

Answer (score -1):

[SFINAE is not yet properly supported in VS2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx)

Though it seem to be possible (notice that I only check for presence of specific overload):

```
#include <type_traits>

template< typename T, typename = void > struct
has_push_back
{
    static bool const value = false;
};

template< typename T > struct
has_push_back
<
    T
,   typename ::std::enable_if_t
    <
        ::std::is_same
        <
            void
        ,   decltype(::std::declval< T >().push_back(::std::declval< typename T::value_type >()))
        >::value
    >
>
{
    static bool const value = true;
};

::std::cout << has_push_back< int >::value << ::std::endl; // 0
::std::cout << has_push_back< ::std::vector< int > >::value << ::std::endl; // 1
```

Comment: You're right about the fact that VS2015 does not properly support SFINAE, but I've solved my problem using a different method. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you post it here as another answer then?

Comment: No, it does solve my problem, but not answer my question